# Remove a class from directive on all host attached to it

Tags: angular, angular5

The directive is simple, to toggle a CSS class to highlight the menu on click event, I want only one menu highlighted right now the behaviour is highlighting all the menu when navigating to another menu, I need to remove the highlight class from the previous menu, how can I do that?

here's my code:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlightMenu]'
})
export class HighlightMenuDirective {

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }
  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.highlight('menu-highlight');
  }
  private highlight(className: string) {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.elem.nativeElement, className)
  }
  private removeHighlight(className: string){
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.elem.nativeElement, className)
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="p-2 border-right menu"  appHighlightMenu routerLink="/unit-requests">
    <div class="flex-column">
        <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i></div>
        <div class="text-center">Requests</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="p-2 border-right menu" appHighlightMenu routerLink="/search-requests">
     <div class="flex-column">
         <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-2x"></i></div>
         <div class="text-center">Search</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using 'appHighlightMenu' on every element, create a parent container for all the elements you want to have 'appHighlightMenu' on. Then using the click event in angular, you can have the instance of the clicked element and then using renderer2, you could highlight the element that was clicked. 
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Try This:

```
private highlight(className: string) {
        $(this.elem.nativeElement).siblings().removeClass('className');
        this.renderer.addClass(this.elem.nativeElement, className)
    }
```